# chrome shows harm experience error on my file in node.js express

Tags: node.js, express, zip

Chrome blocks my file on browser. (may harm your browsing experience so chrome has blocked it)

Is Problem on my code? or my file?

**uploads/**

```
uploads/
  - Miu/
    - face.png
    - bulb.png
  - sella/
    - face.png
    - key.png
```

**HTML**

```html
<a href="/qurare/magic/library/librarian.zip" target="_blank">Download!</a>
```

**Node.js Router**

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const fs = require('fs');
const { zip } = require('zip-a-folder');

router.get('/qurare/magic/library/librarian.zip', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await zip('uploads/', 'public/library.zip'); // it makes zip file which contains uploads/
        await res.download('public/library.zip');
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: try just `/qurare/magic/library/library` this route in your server side and 
`<a href="/qurare/magic/library/librarian" target="_blank">Download!</a>`
this in your HTML

Comment: @iLiA Oh, It's my mistyping :( that path is like `/foo/bar` because real path has private information. real path is correct but error didn't solved yet.